# HTML5/CSS3 Guides or tutorials

Tags: html, css

Are there any highly recommended resources for getting started with HTML5 and CSS3 for designing web applications?

Seems to be the wave of the future..Lets hear everyones thoughts

Comment: If ever there was a question that is asking to be set as Community Wiki, this is it.

Comment: Ill take that as a compliment lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_reference.asp

Answer (score 1):

I saw this the other day and it is super awesome

http://html5boilerplate.com/

> HTML5 Boilerplate is the professional badass's base HTML/CSS/JS template for a fast, robust and future-proof site.
>
> After more than two years in iterative development, you get the best of the best practices baked in: cross-browser normalization, performance optimizations, even optional features like cross-domain Ajax and Flash. A starter apache .htaccess config file hooks you the eff up with caching rules and preps your site to serve HTML5 video, use @font-face, and get your gzip zipple on.
>
> Boilerplate is not a framework, nor does it prescribe any philosophy of development, it's just got some tricks to get your project off the ground quickly and right-footed.

Answer (score 0):

There are about 20 articles covering specific aspects of HTML5 and CSS3 on Dev.Opera. See http://dev.opera.com/articles/tags/open%20web/ for an overview.